# Error code: 800a03f6 when trying to run Node JS on Visual Studio code editor

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to run the command: `npx create-react-app myapp` on Visual Stusio code editor and I'm getting this error:

> C:\Users"My user name"\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js config get cache --parseable"

This is the message I'm getting:

```
Script: C\:Users\My user name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
Line: 1
Char: 1
Error: Invalid character
Code: 800A03F6
Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error
```

I checked the versions of Node and Npm and they are both upgraded.